# Caracteres especiais diferença XAMPP e NGINX

Tags: php, xampp, nginx

Bom estou migrando um sistema que esta rodando no xampp para o nginx,

so que os caracteres especiais no xampp funciona normal, mas no nginx da erro,

alguma dica para solucionar esse problema, o php do xampp e o 7.2.5, e o php do nginx e o 7.3.5

o charset padrão dos 2 servidor está UTF-8

alguem ja passou por esse problema?

o erro que da na api:

```php
{
    "message": "Slim Application Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "type": "RuntimeException",
            "code": 5,
            "message": "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded",
            "file": "\/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/Http\/Response.php",
            "line": 353,
            "trace": [
                "#0 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/index.php(693): Slim\\Http\\Response->withJson(Array, 300)",
                "#1 [internal function]: Closure->{closure}(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Array)",
                "#2 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/Handlers\/Strategies\/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Array)",
                "#3 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/Route.php(335): Slim\\Handlers\\Strategies\\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Array)",
                "#4 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/classes\/gastroz.class.php(140): Slim\\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#5 [internal function]: Auth->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Object(Slim\\Route))",
                "#6 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Auth), Array)",
                "#7 [internal function]: Slim\\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Object(Slim\\Route))",
                "#8 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func(Object(Slim\\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response), Object(Slim\\Route))",
                "#9 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\\Route->Slim\\{closure}(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#10 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/Route.php(313): Slim\\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#11 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/App.php(513): Slim\\Route->run(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#12 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#13 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/App.php(406): Slim\\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#14 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/vendor\/slim\/slim\/Slim\/App.php(314): Slim\\App->process(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))",
                "#15 \/usr\/local\/nginx\/html\/pHpServer-ADm\/api\/index.php(4296): Slim\\App->run()",
                "#16 {main}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: *Informação:* O XAMPP, é uma ferramenta de comumente utilizada para desenvolvimento web, que gerencia alguns componentes úteis para a prática, são eles: Perl, PHP, MySQL, e o Apache (Sendo este último o servidor WEB). ou seja, a questão está relacionada ao Apache e ao nginx.

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus adicionei ao http{  charset utf-8; } e mesmo assim não funcionou